# Removing all falsy values from a javascript array, including NaN but excluding 0 and empty strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nan, falsy

I have the following array:

```
const values = ['', 0, 'one', NaN, 1, 'two', 2, null, 'three', undefined, 3, false];
```

I would like to `filter()` out *all* the `falsy` values ***except*** for `''` and `0`.

I understand there is useful shorthand:

```
return values.filter(Boolean)
```

but this removes all the `falsy` values *including* `''` and `0`.

I have tried the following, instead:

```
return values.filter(value => [NaN, null, undefined, false].indexOf(value) < 0);
```

and it's almost right... but it does not remove `NaN`.

```js
const values = ['', 0, 'one', NaN, 1, 'two', 2, null, 'three', undefined, 3, false];

const filteredValues = values.filter(value => [NaN, null, undefined, false].indexOf(value) < 0);

console.log(filteredValues);
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result as this last example, but also remove `NaN`?

Comment: Add `&& !isNaN(value)` to the end of your filter?

Comment: Just add an `if ( ... )` for when `value` is falsy to test for `""` and `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to itself (i.e. `NaN === NaN` evaluates to false), thus using it with `indexOf` fails. Another approach that also conveys your goal ("filter() out all the falsy values except for '' and 0") better is the following:

```js
const values = ['', 0, 'one', NaN, 1, 'two', 2, null, 'three', undefined, 3, false];
const filteredValues = values.filter(value => value || value === '' || value === 0);
console.log(filteredValues);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
values.filter(value => value || value === '' || value === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using a **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)** since you can check if a set contains `NaN` and the time complexity for `has` is `O(1)`, rather than `O(n)`, where n is the number of items you need to check:

```js
const values = ['', 0, 'one', NaN, 1, 'two', 2, null, 'three', undefined, 3, false];
const notAllowed = new Set([NaN, null, undefined, false]);
const result = values.filter(val => !notAllowed.has(val));
console.log(result);
```